# CSS an javascript gone after I click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, spring-mvc

Currently I have a problem on all the pages.The page contains a form with a submit button and a table that contains buttons.The problem is whenever I click on edit button from `the table` the `css`and`javascript` are gone.

Here is jascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#datatable').dataTable();
        var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
            'aButtons' : [  ],
            'sSwfPath' : 'js/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'

        });

        $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#datatable_wrapper');
    });
</script>
```

The table

```
<table id="datatable" class="hover" >
                <thead>

            <tr>
                <th width="80">Poll ID</th>
                <th width="120">Poll Name</th>
                <th width="120">Poll Description</th>
                <th width="120">poll publisher</th>


                <th width="60">Edit</th>
                <th width="60">Delete</th>
                <th width="60">Voter</th>
                                <th width="60">Afficher courbe</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
                <tfoot>

            <tr>
                <th width="80">Poll ID</th>
                <th width="120">Poll Name</th>
                <th width="120">Poll Description</th>
                <th width="120">poll publisher</th>


                <th width="60">Edit</th>
                <th width="60">Delete</th>
                <th width="60">Voter</th>
                                <th width="60">Afficher Courbe</th>

            </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <c:forEach items="${listpolls}" var="poll">
                    <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>${poll.id_poll}</td>
                    <td>${poll.titre}</td>
                    <td>${poll.description}</td>
                    <td>${poll.emp_login}</td>



                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/poll/edit/${poll.id_poll}' />">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/poll/remove/${poll.id_poll}' />">Delete</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/poll/voter/${poll.id_poll}' />">Vote</a></td>
                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/sa/${poll.id_poll}' />">Afficher courbe</a></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
                            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Here is an picture of the table before i click on edit.

[image]

And now

[image]

As you can see css and javascipt code are both gone.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems you are going to the page `/poll/edit/${poll.id_poll}`, does the CSS and JS exist on that webpage?

Comment: Actually **/poll/edit/${poll.id_poll}** is redirected to the same page .

Comment: Compare the CSS and JS request URLs in browsers network tab, before and after page redirection.

Comment: When i use element inspector  the css and js are present before i click on edit after that the script to make the datatable appear like on  the first picture but the link references to the css and js  are still on the page .

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: The consol detect the js and css links but doesn't find the files, it says  **[HTTP/1.1 404 Not found 11 ms]** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the `/poll/edit/...` etc. in link's href. Even if redirected, browser still thinks you're in different directory from where relative paths to your styles & scripts won't work.

Specify base directory for all links on page:
`<base href="http://www.domain.com/somebasedir/" />`

Then regardless of the redirection, for example this stylesheet:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/style.css" />`

should always be looked for in:
`/somebasedir/path/style.css`

Comment: I added that base thing and replaced **<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>** with **<script src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"/>" ></script>** it worked  ,thank you for your help .